# Instantiate SecKeychainRef and use in Golang using Cgo

Tags: objective-c, macos, go, certificate, keychain

I'm new to development on macOS environment, in Go & Objective-C. I'm trying to implement code in Go that can import an identity (.p12) into keychain.

While I'm able to find a library (https://github.com/github/smimesign/blob/main/certstore/certstore_darwin.go#L83) that does this but when I try to use it to import the identity into System keychain, it doesn't work.

I believe I need to add a value of `SecKeychainRef` (pointing to the System keychain) to the dictionary `options` as documented here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1396915-secpkcs12import?language=objc.

I'm not sure how to achieve this using Obj-C and Go. Please help me with any pointers.

[image: code snippet where this needs to be implemented]

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to solve this using [SecKeychainOpen](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1396431-seckeychainopen?language=objc) but it is deprecated and I'm trying to find a different way to instantiate `SecKeychainRef`

[image: updated code]